# Adjust area from geom_area to a line from geom_line

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a hourly dispatch curve with generation and energy consumpsion data, which have the characteristic that when we do a power balance (generation minus consumpsion) we get values nearly to zero.
Into the generation data there are also net interchange values, that be negative when de power system are exporting energy and positive when the system are importing energy to complete the consumption.
[image]
 Thus,  to the plot created with `geom_area` and `geom_line` be ok, the black line (consumption) needs be adjusted with the generation area, so that there's no gap between the area and the black line.  But, in my attempts I couldn't do it.   How you can see,  same the energy balence resulting in zero, there are a gap beetwen 19 and 20 hours.  I don't know what is wrong. Someone have idea how to do that?
Thanks in advance.

Data to the plot:

```r
generation <-
  data.frame('dayHour' = c('18/11/2018 18:00','18/11/2018 19:00','18/11/2018 20:00','18/11/2018 21:00','18/11/2018 18:00','18/11/2018 19:00','18/11/2018 20:00','18/11/2018 21:00','18/11/2018 18:00','18/11/2018 19:00','18/11/2018 20:00','18/11/2018 21:00','18/11/2018 18:00','18/11/2018 19:00','18/11/2018 20:00','18/11/2018 21:00'),
             'power' = c(-1364.290, -433.110, 1132.39, 749.48, 463.75, 467.8, 469.35, 436.51, 2025.5, 2133.07, 2306.85, 2304.91, 211.52, 213.16, 214.33, 214.59),
             'label' = c('net interchange', 'net interchange', 'net interchange', 'net interchange', 'gas', 'gas', 'gas', 'gas', 'hydro', 'hydro', 'hydro', 'hydro', 'biomass', 'biomass', 'biomass', 'biomass'))


generation$label <- factor(generation$label, levels = c('net interchange', 'gas', 'hydro', 'biomass'))

net.load <- 
  data.frame('dayHour' = c('18/11/2018 18:00', '18/11/2018 19:00', '18/11/2018 20:00', '18/11/2018 21:00'), 'power' = c(1336.48, 2380.91, 4122.91, 3705.49), 'label' = c('net load', 'net load', 'net load', 'net load'))


generation$dayHour <-
  as.POSIXct(strptime(generation$dayHour,format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'))

net.load$dayHour <- 
  as.POSIXct(strptime(net.load$dayHour,format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'))
```

Power balance

```r
pb <- 
filter(generation, label == "biomass")$power +
filter(generation, label == "hydro")$power +
filter(generation, label == "gas")$power +
filter(generation, label == "net interchange")$power -
net.load$power

summary(pb)
```

Dispatch curve

```r
ggplot() + 

  geom_area(data = generation,
            aes(y = power,
                x = dayHour,
                fill = label)) + 

  geom_line(data = net.load,
            aes(y = power,
                x = dayHour,
                colour = label),
            size = 1.2,
            colour = "black")  +

      labs(fill = "generation",
         colour = 'net load')
```

Comment: This is a great first question - thanks for the reproducible data!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like `position_stack` is getting confused when the interpolation crosses the x-axis.

To fix it, you can interpolate manually before plotting (e.g. with `approx`):

```r
library(tidyverse)

generation <- data.frame(
    dayHour = structure(c(1542585600, 1542589200, 1542592800, 1542596400, 1542585600, 1542589200, 1542592800, 1542596400, 1542585600, 1542589200, 1542592800, 1542596400, 1542585600, 1542589200, 1542592800, 1542596400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""),
    power = c(-1364.29, -433.11, 1132.39, 749.48, 463.75, 467.8, 469.35, 436.51, 2025.5, 2133.07, 2306.85, 2304.91, 211.52, 213.16, 214.33, 214.59),
    label = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("net interchange", "gas", "hydro", "biomass"), class = "factor")
)

generation_interpolated <- generation %>% 
    group_by(label) %>% 
    summarise(data = list(as_tibble(approx(dayHour, power, n = 501)))) %>% 
    unnest() %>% 
    mutate(x = as.POSIXct(x, origin = '1970-01-01', tz = 'UTC')) 

net_power_interpolated <- generation_interpolated %>% 
    group_by(x) %>% 
    summarise(y = sum(y))

ggplot(generation_interpolated, aes(x, y)) + 
    geom_area(aes(fill = label)) + 
    geom_line(data = net_power_interpolated)
```

[image: line that fits areas]

To see how `approx` works, a simpler, ungrouped example:

```r
df <- data.frame(x = c(0, 5, 10), y = c(0, 20, 10))
interpolated <- approx(df$x, df$y, n = 11)
str(interpolated)
#> List of 2
#>  $ x: int [1:11] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
#>  $ y: num [1:11] 0 4 8 12 16 20 18 16 14 12 ...

ggplot(as.data.frame(interpolated), aes(x, y)) + 
    geom_line() + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_point(data = df, color = 'dodgerblue', size = 4)
```

[image]

Comment: It's worked well for me.  A only observation is that the date time was shifted to different hours. Can this confusion from `position_stack` be considered a bug?

Comment: Yep, I think it's a variation on [this issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2883)